Instagram Graph api - IGApiException: Unsupported request - method type: get
I hope your day is going well. When I make a request using this endpoint:
  url = "https://graph.instagram.com/access_token"
  params = {
      "grant_type": "ig_exchange_token",
      "client_secret": client_secret,
      "access_token": short_lived_access_token
  }

I encounter the following error:
{'error': {'message': 'Unsupported request - method type: post', 'type': 'IGApiException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'Ape_-PbPFO_idh_eqtMB3jz'}}

I'm unsure of the problem. I have added a verified business, but I have not submitted my app for app review. Should I do that first?
Additionally, it's not just this endpoint; I encounter issues with every endpoint I attempt to request, although I can obtain the short-lived access token without any issues.
I tried to exchange short lived token for the long lived once, and I was expecting to recieve the long lived token

It got fixed, just ask for a ap review and everything will start working

Can you please let me know how to ask the app review?
